# iOS push notification coming twice

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

I am using the one signal third party sdk to send push notification, for this, i had created ssl certificate and export p12 to one signal dashboard.

For some reason my own server need to send push notification for this I have created another SSL certificate and give pem to the my server side.

Once my server send push notification, one signal also send push notification, what is issue anyone suggest me to solve this type of problem.

How to solve this type of issue.

Comment: Not enough information.  Perhaps you've registered for the notification in more than one place?

Comment: Actually I have created two ssl certificates, one for one signal and another for My own server, both uses the APNS

Comment: I think it's pretty clear push notification coming twice because it's sent by onesignal and the server. @NazishAli What is the reason that your server need to send push notif as well? If that's the case can't you just stop using onesignal?

Comment: I have also to use one signal for some cases, but when I send push notification to only my own server, why one signal send push to APNS

Comment: Any one can help me about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal is designed to never deliver the same notification to the same device, so it seems like the likely cause of this issue is that you are delivering the notification twice yourself (once through your own server, and then another time through OneSignal).